# How to find all roots of nonlinear function - an example.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

How would I find all the roots of the function $f(x) = \sin (10x) - 2x$?

I know all sin functions have multiple roots and so this function can also have multiple roots but how would I find all these roots? Using matlab `fzero` which uses the bracket criteria for the existence of solution only gives one root to the function which is 0.25957.

Can I report all the roots from the graph? Or How would I do to find all the multiple roots from the graph? Could there a better way of finding all these multiple roots?

[image]

Graph is due to MATLAB

```
fplot( @(x) sin(10*x)-2*x, [-.5,.5])
%ploting the function with interval [-.5, .5]
grid on
```

Comment: Use better brackets for roots.  $\frac2\pi\theta\leq\sin(\theta)\leq \theta$ for all $\theta\in[0,\frac\pi2]$ should come in handy bounding the roots away from $0$.

Comment: I don't understand why you say "And I don't know how to report the roots by looking at the graph". By looking at the graph, you can look at the places where the graph crosses the x-axis (the horizontal line labeled 0 on the left). You can estimate that $x=0, x=\pm 0.26$ are approximate solutions (of course $x=0$ is exact, since the function is odd). Is the problem that you don't know how to read these things off the graph? Or is there some other requirement?

Comment: @NickD moving the dot-point on the curve shows that $x = -0.2508, y=-0.09043$ am I missing something? How would I accurately read the solution from the graph from your point of view?

Comment: I meant "eyeball it": the positive zero is between 0.2 and 0.3. I can see that it's a bit to the right of the middle of that interval, so it's bigger that 0.25, but it's not as big as 0.27, so 0.26 (and since the function is odd, the negative root is roughly -0.26).That's about the best you can do with the resolution of the graph above, but that would be a decent starting point e.g. for a Newton if you need better accuracy.

Comment: You say "The graph doesn't get the job done as I would have expected". What is the job that the graph does not do? What did you expect? The graph tells you that there are three zeros in the interval $[-0.5, 0.5]$ and it tells you (roughly) what those zeros are: what else do you want  to know?

Comment: Three zeros means three solutions to the function? Would that be all the solutions?

Comment: Yes, these  are all the solutions of the *equation* $f(x) = 0$ in the given interval (it turns out that these are all the solutions over the whole real line, but the graph of course is limited to the interval $[-0.5, 0.5]$ and cannot indicate anything about what happens outside that interval - but it is fairly easy to prove that there are no solutions outside that interval).

Comment: Maybe this will help: if $f(x) = \sin(10x) - 2x$, define two functions: $F(x) = \sin(10x)$ and $G(x) = 2x$. Then $f(x) = 0$ if and only if $F(x) = G(x)$ i.e. where their graphs intersect. Now plot $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ and see where that happens. If you enlarge the plotting interval to say $[-1, 1]$, you'll get a pretty clear picture.

Comment: Plotting both functions on the same graph gives the normal spiral sin function curve. I cannot see the straight line $G(x)$ - I have tried several intervals and it didn't show $G(x)$. Is there a way I can do to see the straight line intersecting $F(x)$ in matlab?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%2810x%29%2C+2x

Comment: It seems different intervals will give different solution estimates right? So in conclusion can we conclude that the function has many roots and these roots depends on the intervals?

Answer (score 2):

Since the function is odd, you can limit the problem to the positive solution(s) for $0 \leq x \leq \frac 12$.

Since $x=0$ is a trivial solution, just focus on the next one. You have
$$f(x) = \sin (10x) - 2x$$
$$f'(x)=10 \cos(10x)-2$$

The first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=\frac{1}{10} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)$$ and the second derivative test confirms that this is a maximum.

Expand $f(x)$ around $x_*$
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{6}}{5}-\frac{1}{5} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right)-20 \sqrt{6} \left(x-\frac{1}{10} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{10} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right)^3\right)$$ then, as an *estimate*,
$$x=\frac{1}{10} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)+\frac{1}{10}\sqrt{2 -\frac 1{\sqrt 6} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)} \sim 0.2570$$ while the "exact" solution, obtained using Newton method, is $0.2596$.

**Edit**

For the fun of it, let $x=\frac t{10}$ and use the $1{,}400$ years old approximation
$$\sin(t) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -t) t}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -t) t}\qquad (0\leq t\leq\pi)$$ and you just need to solve a quadartic equation in $t$ and the *approximate* solution is
$$x=-1+\frac{\pi }{20}+\frac{1}{10} \sqrt{100+(10-\pi) \pi }\approx 0.259560$$ instead of $0.259574$.

Comment: Bonus: the estimate can be used to start Newton's method.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. Have a look at my edit. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. You solution gives one root to the function, that's good. But I need how to find all the roots (if possible) or how would you conclude (with reasons) that the function has multiple roots?